# shell script for AWS run-tasks outside of normal schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ecs

Currently have some task-based automation for ECS that run on a scheduled basis, however sometimes there is a need to run only run task or re-run tasks for only a certain kinds of tasks (for example sql tasks or datadog tasks).

I know this can be done via console, but it's inefficient. Was thinking of a bash script that calls to start a task from a CLI. Currently I know I can do this with the AWS CLI using '--task-definition', but it's not much better. I don't usually write scripts, so I'm basically here to help with brainstorming. I'm wondering if there is a way to make an API call to start tasks. Would I need to type in the ARN every time? Can I just list the tasks on the AWS CLI and have the exported to the script? Would network-config need to be hard-coded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The AWS API calls to start a task are:

- [StartTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_StartTask.html):

  > Starts a new task from the specified task definition on the specified container instance or instances.
- [RunTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html):

  > Starts a new task using the specified task definition. You can allow Amazon ECS to place tasks for you, or you can customize how Amazon ECS places tasks using placement constraints and placement strategies.

Since this is AWS API calls, there are equivalent calls in CLI and SDK.